# faker npm package for get name with specific gender

Tags: faker

I use faker npm package in Node v10.8.0 and npm v6.3.0 for generate user's with gender, but doesn't work for me :c

See code below

```
const genders = ['male', 'female'];

let gender = faker.random.arrayElement(genders);
let name = faker.name.firstName(gender);
```

And the result is something like this :

```
gender : male
name : Lourdes
```

Answer (score -1):

According to the comments/docs in the `faker` lib, firstName is picked randomly if it doesn't exist in your locale data. I would strongly suggest not making your tests or code depend on gender-specific info, since that's fuzzy and is subject to change.